# Can you increase the microbiota in an insect?

Tags: entomology, microbiology, microbiome

I know you can suppress the microbiota of an insect with antibiotics, but I´m am looking for a way to increase it. For example, can I feed an insect with something that helps boost the bacteria like agar or something.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is absolutely yes. 
There are 3 main ways:

1. Faecal transplant: faecal sample from other insect could be
   transplanted in order to colonize the gastro-intestinal tract
2. Injection of bacterial culture into the desired tissue
3. Use of functional foods to increase the abundance of specific bacterial
   genus.

See [this review](https://academic.oup.com/femsre/article/37/5/699/542120) for more detail